# How do I secure X server against spyware in a GUI application?

Tags: linux, malware, spyware, desktop

Suppose you have a GUI application, that potentionally may be too curious about your environment, such as the list of window titles.

How do I limit application's ability to enumerate windows, capture unrelated input, access clipboard when not asked to, preserving most of normal activity?

How do I give partial, not full access to X?

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10978/firewall-for-x-applications

Answer (score 1):

As an immediate patch, you should run such an application in a separate X server on a different VT. This is the only way you can guarantee that the app does not use the X API to spy on other clients. You may also try your hand at [XSELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_XWIN) but I know of very few people in the world who know how to run it, and it usually severely limits what your target app can do (not to mention the cost of labelling your desktop's data properly).

Besides, you still need to prevent process code injections or introspection, and to prevent the app from tampering with your users' runtime environment by sandboxing it (you need mount and IPC namespaces at least). See [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [MBox](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/mbox/). Note that I don't discuss exploits against the kernel / namespaces / X servers, just available Desktop capabilities.

On the longer term, display protocol like Wayland that guarantee isolation between clients from the start will be available. Until then we must cope with the insecurity of the Linux desktop.

Comment: `Until then we must cope with the insecurity ` -> Maybe [implement a Xephyr modification](http://superuser.com/questions/126321/how-to-make-xephyr-to-hide-its-background-rootless-mode-like-in-cygwin-x) to act as a "firewall". Xephyr already can provice some isolation, but at expence of confort. Maybe we can move from safe way to safe+comfortable way by modifying Xephyr...

Comment: Yeah I thought of mentioning Xephyr but as you say you would need to modify it to prevent any API call that would break the isolation you want to impose. X11 is not quite the dream protocol for that kind of experiments because it has grown insanely. You'd need to review what can be done with Xephyr's API to leak information from other clients, then modify Xephyr accordingly and fix whatever issues occurred.

Comment: @Steve_DL, I mean I think Xephyr should already provide necessary isolation (unless something is badly written in Xephyr itself), but is not very convenient (no rootless mode). So we can add convenience to existing security, which can be simpler than the reverse.

Comment: No rootless will be a detail of the past some day soon, with user namespaces you could trick a Xephyr into acting as a X11 client fairly easily. The problem lies in the API that Xephyr exposes to its own clients and whether it's safe to use or not. This might explain better: mupuf.org/blog/2014/02/19/wayland-compositors-why-and-how-to-handle/

Comment: As for "convenience", it's called usability ans since i'm a usability *and* security expert, no it's not easier ;) you must consider all requirements from the start, you can't plug in usability. See www.computer.org/csdl/mags/sp/2004/05/j5019.pdf for a starter

Comment: By "rootless" I mean "without a [visible] root window", not "running not as root user". Think of VirtualBox's "seamless" mode.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/). It implements X11 sandboxing with the help of either Xpra or Xephyr.